# Producer-consumer problem with a twist

Tags: java, concurrency, clojure

- The producer is finite, as should be the consumer.

  - The problem is when to stop, *not* how to run.
- Communication can happen over *any* type of BlockingQueue.

  - Can't rely on poisoning the queue(PriorityBlockingQueue)
  - Can't rely on locking the queue(SynchronousQueue)
  - Can't rely on offer/poll exclusively(SynchronousQueue)
  - Probably even more exotic queues in existence.

> Creates a queued seq on another (presumably lazy) seq s. The queued
>    seq will produce a concrete seq in the background, and can get up to
>    n items ahead of the consumer. n-or-q can be an integer n buffer
>    size, or an instance of java.util.concurrent BlockingQueue. Note
>    that reading from a seque can block if the reader gets ahead of the
>    producer.

http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/seque

My attempts so far + some tests: https://gist.github.com/934781

Solutions in Java or Clojure appreciated.

Comment: In Java, I would just use an ExecutorService or a class which wraps it to handle all the event types you need as it can do all the events you mention and much more.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Reader {

    private final ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private final List<Object> completed = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private final BlockingQueue<Object> doneQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>();
    private int pending = 0;

    public synchronized Object take() {
        removeDone();
        queue();
        Object rVal;
        if(completed.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                rVal = doneQueue.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            pending--;
        } else {
            rVal = completed.remove(0);
        }
        queue();
        return rVal;
    }

    private void removeDone() {
        Object current = doneQueue.poll();
        while(current != null) {
            completed.add(current);
            pending--;
            current = doneQueue.poll();
        }
    }

    private void queue() {
        while(pending < 10) {
            pending++;
            ex.submit(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doneQueue.add(compute());
                }

                private Object compute() {
                    //do actual computation here
                    return new Object();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 background thread produces up to 10 results in advance, as results are taken in the foreground, the background thread generates new results, if no results are available, take blocks until a new result is available

Comment: Well yes, but I said the producer is finite, and the the main problem is *stopping*. If there are no more results, this is just going to sit there forever.

Comment: When you say "Can't rely on poisoning the queue(PriorityBlockingQueue)" do you mean you can't add a DONE marker to doneQueue, or you can't use PriorityBlockingQueue?

Comment: I mean that PriorityBlockingQueue throws an exception deep inside when you insert a marker.

Comment: That should be solveable, its probably because you are inserting null, or you are inserting a DONE marker that is not Comparable with the other elements of the Queue

Comment: Yes, it should be comparable with the rest, but also be guaranteed to come out last. PriorityBlockingQueue isn't FIFO of course.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer I'm afraid, but a few remarks and more questions. My first answer would be: use `clojure.core/seque`. The producer needs to communicate end-of-seq somehow for the consumer to know when to stop, and I assume the number of produced elements is not known in advance. Why can't you use an EOS marker (if that's what you mean by queue poisoning)?

If I understand your alternative `seque` implementation correctly, it will break when elements are taken off the queue outside your function, since `channel` and `q` will be out of step in that case: channel will hold more `#(.take q)` elements than there are elements in `q`, causing it to block. There might be ways to ensure `channel` and `q` are always in step, but that would probably require implementing your own `Queue` class, and it adds so much complexity that I doubt it's worth it.

Also, your implementation doesn't distinguish between normal EOS and abnormal queue termination due to thread interruption - depending on what you're using it for you might want to know which is which. Personally I don't like using exceptions in this way — use exceptions for exceptional situations, not for normal flow control.